# Bash: display effective file content without comments and empty lines

Tags: bash, grep, cat

Lets say I have a configuration file (`stuff.conf`) which looks like this (my real file is around ~ 1000 lines) :

```
# Some comment
foo=bar

# Other comment
foobar=barfoo

# Another one
abc=123 # inline comment
....
```

I want to display the effective values in this file, without any comments or empty lines. What I would like to print is this :

```
foo=bar
foobar=barfoo
abc=123
...
```

I can strip the empty lines and the comment lines with this:

```
cat stuff.conf | grep -v "#" | grep -v "^$"
```

But it also strip the lines where the comment marker (`#`) is not at the beggining of the line (e.g.: `abc=123 # inline comment`). The output looks like this:

```
foo=bar
foobar=barfoo
...
```

## Question:

How can I manage to display all the line that doesn't start with `#` or blank lines? In the special case of `abc=123 # inline comment` I don't care if the comment at the end of the line is displayed.

Comment: do you need to keep tabulation/indentation or strip it as well ?

Comment: It would be nice to keep the tab/indentation; but it's OK if you have a solution where tabs/indentation are not keeped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sed` you can do this:

```
sed -E '/^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)/d; s/#.*//' file

foo=bar
foobar=barfoo
abc=123
```

- Regex `/^[[:blank:]]*(#|$)/` will match all lines with `#` at start with optional white-spaces before or if there is only an empty  line with white-spaces.
- `/d` will delete those lines and
- `s/#.*//` will delete inline comments.

Comment: OP mentioned in his desired output that he would like to remove the `#inline comment` as well

Comment: May the Gods of regex bless you :) Thanks for your answer @anubhava

Answer (score 3):

With your command:

```
cat stuff.conf | grep -v "#" | grep -v "^$"
```

In the same way you avoided the blank lines with `grep -v "^$"`, you can do the same with the lines starting with "#", that is "^#", as follows:

```
cat stuff.conf | grep -v "^#" | grep -v "^$"
```

Said that, note the useless of that `cat` command and it is also better use one only grep, I mean:

```
grep -v "^#\|^$" stuff.conf
```

But this won't remove inline comments, for that you may remove any sentence from a "#" character appearance in any position of the file with `sed`, that is:

```
grep -v "^#\|^$" stuff.conf | sed -e "s/#.*$//g"
```

Comment: same problem as anubhava first solution, this doesn't remove inline comments

Comment: @Aserre Sure, was trying to find the way to do it also with `grep`, but wasn't able, so finally I had to use `sed` too.